# C++ Pointer - ressignment in a function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I was recently reviewing Google's [C++ materials](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/cpp/basics/index.html) and came across the [following code](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/cpp/basics/cpp-in-depth.html) for demonstrating pointers

```
void Unknown(int *p, int num);
void HardToFollow(int *p, int q, int *num);

void Unknown(int *p, int num) {
 int *q;

 q = &num;
 *p = *q + 2;
 num = 7;
}

void HardToFollow(int *p, int q, int *num) {
 *p = q + *num;
 *num = q;
 num = p;
 p = &q;
 Unknown(num, *p);
}

main() {
 int *q;
 int trouble[3];

 trouble[0] = 1;
 q = &trouble[1];
 *q = 2;
 trouble[2] = 3;

 HardToFollow(q, trouble[0], &trouble[2]);
 Unknown(&trouble[0], *q);

 cout << *q << " " << trouble[0] << " " << trouble[2];
}
```

My question is the following: the q pointer is originally assigned to trouble[1]. When sent into HardToFollow, the q pointer (now called p) is updated to a value of 4, and trouble[1] is subsequently updated as well. Immediately thereafter, the original q pointer (again, called p in this function) is redirected to point to a local variable (p = &q). Nevertheless, by the end of the program, our original q pointer is back to pointing to trouble[1]. How did this happen?

Comment: Where do you see something that changed the `q` pointer? The `q` pointer is not "called p in this function". That function has a pointer called `p` that starts out with the same value as the `q` pointer.

Comment: Note that these are not "c++", but old plain C pointers.

Comment: @IgorR. While C and C++ pointers act for the most part in a similar way, they are not the same thing. C and C++ are different languages; lets not mix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simple modify `main::q` via  passing it to `HardToFollow` function via pass by value. since your're passing `q` to it as pass by value, so in `HardToFollow` you can modify what's pointed by `q` via `p` and `p` itself but you can't modify `q` to point to something else.

slightly modifying the example shall do what you expecting it to :

```
void HardToFollow(int*& p, int q, int *num) {
 *p = q + *num;
 *num = q;
 num = p;
 p = &q;
 //Unknown(num, *p); //forget about this for now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added some comments that make it clear:

```
void HardToFollow(int *p, int q, int *num) {
  /* this modifies the value pointed to by p */
  *p = q + *num;
  *num = q;
  num = p;
  /* this does not modify the original pointer */
  p = &q;
  Unknown(num, *p);
}
```

`[...]`

```
  /* the memory address q points to is copied to the function scope */
  HardToFollow(q, trouble[0], &trouble[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in function Unknown don't working with pointer q from the main function
The function works only with value of the pointer named num